# How can I draw a circumcircle of a triangle in Python Turtle?

Tags: python, geometry, triangle

Please, could you help me with this? I can draw a triangle and also calculate the center of the circle (I don't know if it is even helpful) and I have calculated the radius. But I don't know how to draw a circle itself. The way I have it doesn't connect all the vertexes. Thank you for any ideas.

```
import turtle
import math
from math import pi
alfa=60 # in degrees
beta=40
gama=80
c = 100
sin_alfa = math.sin(pi/180*alfa)  # in radians
sin_beta = math.sin(pi/180*beta)
sin_gama = math.sin(pi/180*gama)
a = c/sin_gama *sin_alfa # a,b calculated
b = c/sin_gama *sin_beta
board = turtle.Turtle()
board.forward(100) # base c 
board.left(180-beta)
board.forward(a)
board.left(180-gama)
board.forward(b)
board.left(180-alfa)
rad = rad = a/2*sin_alfa # radius of a circumcircle
board.circle(rad)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modified code would draw a circle that touches all corners.

```
import turtle
import math
from math import pi
alfa=60 # in degrees
beta=40
gama=80
c = 100
sin_alfa = math.sin(pi/180*alfa)  # in radians
sin_beta = math.sin(pi/180*beta)
sin_gama = math.sin(pi/180*gama)
a = c/sin_gama *sin_alfa # a,b calculated
b = c/sin_gama *sin_beta
board = turtle.Turtle()
board.forward(100) # base c 
board.left(180-beta)
board.forward(a)
board.left(180-gama)
board.forward(b)
board.left(180-alfa)
rad = a/(2*sin_alfa)   # radius of a circumcircle


# shift pen to bottom-most point of the circle
board.up()
board.forward(c/2)
board.right(90)
board.forward(rad*(1-(1-sin_gama**2)**0.5))
board.down()
board.left(90)

# the circle
board.circle(rad)

turtle.done()
```

Here is a graphical explanation of how the cursor was shifted:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for yur answer. I have tried it and the result is this. It is a little bit inaccurate.It's just that turtle is not 100% precise? Is it OK? Thanks again.This is a picture that I get, C vertex seems to be a little off.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/57D2y.png

Comment: @MonikaSistkova You are right, I did a small calculation oopsie. I will post the correction. And yes turtle graphics is not that precise but its usually tolerable. The output that you get is definitely not that tolerable. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Please recheck the code and marked this answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to draw the circle in the middle of the triangle?
if so then all you have to do is

```py
# code for everything and triangle
board.up()
board.forward(50)
board.down()
# Rest of code
```

Please elaborate